# implementing functools.partial that prepends additional arguments

Tags: python, functools

The documentation for [functools.partial](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.partial) says that it is "roughly equivalent to":

```
def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
    def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
        newkeywords = keywords.copy()
        newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
        return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)  # line to change
    newfunc.func = func
    newfunc.args = args
    newfunc.keywords = keywords
    return newfunc
```

If I wanted to implement a version that *prepends* the additional arguments,
it seems like I'd just have to change the indicated line.

Are there any other features/gotchas that I should be worried about in just copying this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the source code for [`_functoolsmodule.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c), I don't think there's much to worry about.

The module implementation of `partial` handles **pickling** and `repr`, but everything else looks like it works as in the documentation so presumably the reason it is implemented in C is just for efficiency.  There is also the fact that it is a type rather than just being a function closure.

Note, however, that in the documentation example `func`, `args`, and `keywords` are purely cosmetic; i.e. they are not overridable as they are with actual `functools.partial` instances.  One alternative would be to subclass `functools.partial`:

```
class rpartial(partial):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kw = self.keywords.copy()
        kw.update(kwargs)
        return self.func(*(args + self.args), **kw)
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of subclassing the builtin.

Comment: This is great, but I think it should read:
    class rpartial(partial):def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kw = self.keywords.copy()
    kw.update(kwargs)
    return self.func(*(args + self.args), **kw)

Answer (score 0):

One pitfall is how your partial assignment would handle arbitrary arguments, such as in the following example:

```
def f(a,b, *args):
    pass
```

Now partially apply `f` to the arguments 1 and 2:

```
g = partial(f, 1, 2)
```

What is the value of the parameter `b` in `g`? Is it 1, or is it still awaiting a value? For that matter, what is the value of `a`? Put another way, how many, if any, of the supplied arguments should be treated as additional arguments.

Comment: This is a good comment, but I'd declare the synatax to mean `g() == f(1,2); g(x)==f(x,1,2); g(x,y)==f(x,y,1,2)` and so on.  Which can be odd, but is systematic.