# passing/changing arguments of a function which is passed as an argument in another function

Tags: python, inspect, functools

I have one weird problem. I want to pass/change an argument of a function which itself is passed as an argument in some other function. See  the below code for more details

```
def generic_method(selector_type='CSS', selector=None, parent_element=None, postfunc=None):

    # Do your stuff and get value of attr_value
    print "Doing Stuff"
    attr_value = '$123.70'

    print "Post-Processing Step"
    if postfunc:
        attr_value = postfunc(attrval=attr_value)

    return attr_value

# The 2 methods below are in separate file 
from functools import partial
def method_in_bot():
    p, q, r = 11, 12, 13
    postfunc = partial(post_processing, 12, p, q, r, post=23)
    value = generic_method('XPATH', '.class-name', 'parent_element', postfunc)
    return value

def post_processing(y=None, *args, **kwargs):
    attr_value = kwargs.get('attrval', 'None')
    if attr_value:
        return attr_value.split('$')
    return []
```

So I passed my `post_processing` method along with all its parameters to  my `generic_method` by using `functools's partial` and also passed a new variable `attrval` to my post_processing method. But what is more desirable is to pass or assign `attr_value`  directly to variable `y` to `post_processing`.

I was looking for ways to modify functions parameters during run-time. I was searching over the net and found out that their is a `inspect` library in python which tells you about the arguments passed to the function. Can it be used in this case.

Comment: > But what is more desirable is to pass or assign attr_value directly to variable y to post_processing. <- Is that the question? Please elaborate a little more about what would you like to achieve.

Comment: Yes instead of postfunc(attrval=attr_value) I would like to call attr_value = postfunc(y=attr_value).

Comment: You _could_ pass a tuple &/or dict of `postfunc` args to `generic_method`. But what you're currently doing is fine, IMHO.  While doing deep magic with `inspect` may make some parts of your code easier to write, it will also make your program harder to read. Ease of reading should generally take priority over ease of writing.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, you could do `def post_processing(*args, y=None, **kwargs):` and that would be it. With Python 2 you have to find a different technique than `partial`. Or maybe subclass it as in [implementing functools.partial that prepends additional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831070/implementing-functools-partial-that-prepends-additional-arguments) .